# Where to find information on villages Jablonow & Suchostaw, Husiatyn, Ukraine (Galicia area, formerly Austria & Poland)?

Tags: poland, ukraine, austria

Looking for information or databases that will help with my research of Jablonow & Suchostaw, Husiatyn, Ukraine.  These two villages are in the area known as Galicia and have in the past been part of Austria and Poland but are now in Ukraine.  Have contacted the Ukrainian Archives but they were unable to help.  The family history library in SLC has very little information for this area.

Comment: Are the people being researched Jewish?

Comment: I found links to some discussion of Jablonow [**here**](http://www.ukraine.com/forums/genealogy/14403-where-jablonow-austria-1897-a.html) and Suchostow [**here**](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/GaliciaPoland-Ukraine/conversations/topics/41305?var=1).

Comment: There is a RootsWeb mailing list GALICIA-L "A mailing list for anyone with a genealogical interest in the former Austrian province of Galicia that was part of the First Partition of Poland in 1772 and is now located in the southeastern part of Poland and the southwestern part of Ukraine." http://lists.rootsweb.ancestry.com/index/intl/POL/GALICIA.html Scroll down the page to browse the archives or to search.

Comment: Thank you for your replies Ikessler, PolyGeo and Jan.  I don't believe the family was Jewish - my Grandfather didn't attend church and my Grandmother passed away when my father was about six, however, my father was baptised Catholic as that was the only church available in northern Alberta at the time. I do have posts on JewishGen and on Rootsweb but not the Galicia site.  I will be checking the information each of you have sent.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What time period are you interested in?

Comment: My grandfather was born in 1888 and my grandmother abt 1896.

Comment: Related: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5548/has-anyone-ever-heard-of-the-town-of-husinice-russia-or-ukraine-circa-1912 It also contains a step-by-step sequence of how to search for Ukrainian towns and villages.

Answer (score 10):

Both towns are listed in Gesher Galicia's [All-Galicia Database](http://www.geshergalicia.org/).

> Gesher Galicia is a 501(c)3 non-profit organization that promotes and
>   conducts Jewish genealogical and historical research for Galicia, a
>   province of the former Austro-Hungarian Empire, which is today part of
>   eastern Poland and southwestern Ukraine. Our major research initiative
>   — The Galician Archival Records Project — is acquiring and indexing a
>   variety of metrical, property, school, voter, tax and magnate records
>   for Galicia. **Although our organization's primary focus is researching
>   Jewish roots in Galicia, the diverse community records in our
>   databases contain names that span all the ethnic and religious groups
>   that once lived in this region.**

See their page [The Galician Archival Records Project (GARP)](http://web.archive.org/web/20150418200822/http://www.geshergalicia.org/projects/garp/) where they explain the purpose of the project, and how to search their database to see what coverage they have for any given town.

Thanks to Elizabeth Shown Mills' [Evidence Explained](https://www.evidenceexplained.com/quicktips/jewish-research-galicia) website for the pointer to this resource.

**Mailing Lists**

Another resource to consider: the RootsWeb mailing list [GALICIA-L](http://lists.rootsweb.ancestry.com/index/intl/POL/GALICIA.html):

> A mailing list for anyone with a genealogical interest in the former
>   Austrian province of Galicia that was part of the First Partition of
>   Poland in 1772 and is now located in the southeastern part of Poland
>   and the southwestern part of Ukraine.

Scroll down the page to browse the archives or to search.

**Societies**

- FEEFHS The Foundation for East European Family History Studies has a page of [Galicia Genealogy Resources](http://feefhs.org/links/galicia.html).

**Other websites**

- [Genealogy  of Halychyna / Eastern Galicia](http://www.halgal.com/index.htm)
- [The Galicia Genealogy and Family Tree Page](http://www.genealogytoday.com/surname/finder.mv?Surname=Galicia) (Surname Finder / Genealogy Today)

Answer (score 6):

I have done research in this area. I have ancestors from [Bilyi Kamin'](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bilyi+Kamin'/@49.9061325,24.8773901,13z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x473aa95952d5e393:0xce076b0bdaea717a), a village about 125 km to the NW. But I have the good fortune of there being a lot of microfilm available from FamilySearch.

Church records will be the most helpful. The trick will be in knowing what churches existed and when. From the records that FamilySearch has you can tell that at least there were Jewish and Greek Catholic congregations in Suchostaw and a Roman Catholic congregation in Jablonow, but we don't know how long. There might also have been other churches, though not likely. A gazetteer would really be helpful in knowing exactly what churches existed for what time periods and where people might have gone when those churches were not in operation (before they were established or after they were closed).

Here are some other links that may help you, or anybody else that comes after you.

**Suchostaw**:

- [Sukhostav (Gesher Galicia)](http://www.geshergalicia.org/towns/sukhostav/)
- [Sukhostav (JewishGen)](http://data.jewishgen.org/wconnect/wc.dll?jg~jgsys~community~-1055614)
- [Sukhostav (JewishGen KehilaLinks)](http://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/suchostaw/sl_suchostaw.htm)
- [Ukraine, Ternopil′, Husi︠a︡tyn, Sukhostav (FamilySearch Catalog)](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&placeId=1185217&query=%2Bplace%3A%22Ukraine%2C%20Ternopil%E2%80%B2%2C%20Husi%EF%B8%A0a%EF%B8%A1tyn%2C%20Sukhostav%22&subjectsOpen=1185461-1)

**Jablonow**:

- [Yablonov (Gesher Galicia)](http://www.geshergalicia.org/towns/yablonov/)
- [Yabloniv (JewishGen)](http://data.jewishgen.org/wconnect/wc.dll?jg~jgsys~community~-1059241)
- [Yablonov (JewishGen KehilaLinks)](http://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Suchostaw/sl_jablonow.htm)
- [Ukraine, Ternopil′, Husi︠a︡tyn, I︠A︡bluniv (FamilySearch Catalog)](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&placeId=144380&query=%2Bplace%3A%22Ukraine%2C%20Ternopil%E2%80%B2%2C%20Husi%EF%B8%A0a%EF%B8%A1tyn%2C%20I%EF%B8%A0A%EF%B8%A1bluniv%22&subjectsOpen=391015-2)

You may know by now that villages in the Galicia area of Ukraine have multiple names: Polish, Ukrainian, Russian, and different spelling variations of those. Try all different spelling variations when searching. When you find a website, forum, or record that appears to be talking about the same village, try to figure out what district it's in to make sure it's the right village. There may be other villages with the same name in a different district. It can be tedious, but it's worth it.

Here are the different names I've seen in the few minutes I've been answering your question:

**Suchostaw**

- Sukhostav
- Suchastov
- Suchstov
- Suchostan
- Suchostav
- Suchostov
- Suchostaw
- Сухостав

**Jablonow**

- Yablonov
- Yablonuv
- Jabłonów
- Jabluniv
- Jabłonów
- I︠A︡bluniv
- Яблунів

In the end you will probably have to verify whether or not records even exist by hiring someone that can visit the Ukrainian Archives for you. There is one person registered with Genlighten that you can hire for research in [Ukraine](http://www.genlighten.com/offerings?country=Ukraine). JewishGen has a listing of [professionals recommended by their users](http://www.jewishgen.org/infofiles/researchers.htm) (you'll have to filter for ones that do research in Galicia and/or Ukraine).

Comment: Thank you again for your most helpful info Justin.  I do have Brian Lenius' "Genealogical Gazetteer of Galicia" which has helped me narrow down Admin Dist, Judicial Dist and Parishes.  I've also been to the Family History Library but they only have microfilm for Jewish records.  As you suggest I will probably have to hire a professional researcher.