# Ancestors in Lemberg (Lviv) and Czyczkow/y

Tags: 19th-century, poland, jewish, austria, bavaria

My great-grandfather was born in Lemberg, Galicia (now Lviv, Ukraine). However, I am unsure how to proceed to further back in the family tree. I have written to the archives in Lviv which hold the records, however I have never heard back. The family name: Mühlgay and my great-great-grandfather's hebrew name: Mordechai (likely not his legal name) are all that I have to go on. I know that Mordechai Mühlgay's father was R' Yoshke (likely Josef or Jozef) of Czyczkow, a local religious leader, however I have little else. What information is available about my ancestors?

Although I am not giving the name of my great-grandfather, I will say that he and his brothers were born over the span of the late 1880s-1890s and that they moved to Fürth, in Bavaria, at some point of the latter decade.

Comment: Hi, Noah -- welcome to G&FH.SE!  While you are waiting for answers, you might find some interesting information by looking at the other Q/As here from other users, especially those who are looking for information about [Galicia](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/search?q=Galicia).

Comment: There was a previous question asking about towns near Lviv. http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/4090/where-to-find-information-on-villages-jablonow-suchostaw-husiatyn-ukraine-g/5290#5290 I suggest reading those answers for some great tips. I could answer this question but I would probably just copy a lot of information from the other answers. I have done some research in the area. Feel free to contact to contact me directly for more help if those answers don't help much. My email address is in my profile.

Answer (score 4):

The good news is that over 100,000 Jewish birth, marriage, and death records from Lviv (Lwow, Lemberg) have been transcribed and put online for free searching in Gesher Galicia's All Galicia Database:

```
http://search.geshergalicia.org/
```

The bad news is that I don't see anyone there named "Mühlgay".  Could your great-grandfather have had a different surname before he moved?  Although, note that the transcribed birth records don't go much past 1871 yet; they're still being worked on by volunteers, and it's possible your family moved to Lviv after that date.  And it's also possible that they lived just outside Lviv and said they were "from" Lviv, in the same way that someone born in a small suburb might refer to themselves as being from the nearby city, if they were referring in conversation to their general area of birth.

I would join the JewishGen and/or Gesher Galicia e-mail mailing lists and post your queries there, with dates or years of birth, if you know them.  The mailing lists are free, and full of very helpful folks.