# Identifying Polish town recorded as Plugazewa, Russia in 1913?

Tags: poland, russia, historical-gazetteer, 1910s

Looking at my maternal grandmother's Ellis Island arrival document shows her hometown recorded as Plugazewa, Russia.  No such place exists with that spelling.

I'm almost certain the town was in what is now Southern Poland or was part of Galicia when that Duchy existed.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what city this may actually have been?

Her name was Janina Magiera, she arrived in 1913.

Comment: Can you please include either a link to the record or an image with the place name? It really helps to be able to see the original handwriting with these Polish place names. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Unfortunately no. All I have is a computer printed generated from - I think - a scanning of the manifest.

Comment: Ok, do you mind sharing your grandmother's name so I can see if I can find the original manifest?

Comment: Her name was Janina Magiera, she arrived in 1913.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  While you are waiting for an answer, try reading some of the previous questions about Galicia to see what resources exist to help you, such as: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/4090/1006

Comment: Hi Stanley, what was the name of the ship and the exact date of arrival? I can't seem to find anyone of that name who arrived in 1913.

Comment: Thanks all, but I have now solved my own mystery. She was from Kyrgz.

Comment: Galicia was part of Austria-Hungary, it was never part of Russia (except if you count WW1 military occupation).

Answer (score 3):

I took a look at the [Słownik geograficzny Królestwa Polskiego i innych krajów słowiańskich](http://dir.icm.edu.pl/Slownik_geograficzny/Tom_VIII/327) (Geographic Dictionary of the Kingdom of Poland and Other Slavic Countries) to see if I find a town with a similar name. The closest town that I could find was [Pługawice](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Plugawice,+Poland/@51.4096061,18.1760498,14z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x471a999dc90a271b:0x54d316f5ffa9c00b!8m2!3d51.4096061!4d18.1935593).

You may want to take a look through the pages of the Słownik to see if there is another town with a similar name